# "I'm starving to death" or "I'm hungry to death" can mean "I'm very hungry"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

Is it acceptable to use the sentence "**I'm starving to death**" or "**I'm hungry to death**" just in the meaning of "*I'm very hungry*" (rather than of a real pathological condition) and then to be said as an alternative to "I'm very hungry"?

Comment: "I'm hungry to death" isn't idiomatic, but "I'm starving to death" is just ordinary exaggeration, used all the time.

Comment: **I'm freezing to death** or **I'm roasting to death** are  similar exaggerations used to mean "it's too chilly|hot for me" where the plain adjective doesn't work; we don't say "I'm cold|hot to death".   **to death** complements an ongoing *process* not a state.

Answer (score 1):

[starve to death
is an idiom](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/starve%20to%20death)

> to die from lack of food

> The famine caused many to starve to death.

*hungry to death* is uncommon.  "BE + hungry to death" is much less common than "BE + starving to death".
 [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=be_INF+starving+to+death%2C%28hungry+to+death+*+10%29&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

If we do want to make such exaggerations, we should choose the established form.

Edit

You may consider also “I’m famished” as @Paul Tanenbaum suggested.

Comment: “I’m starving,” “I’m starving to death,” and “I’m famished” are all very, very commonly used (hyperbolically) to mean simply “I’m very hungry.”

Comment: Yes, agreed.  "famished" is a good word.